# Request user input based on an unknown number of mac addresses in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, select

I need to write a quick bash script that asks the user which mac address should be used as a variable in the rest of the script.  I can get the mac addresses using the following

```
ip addr | grep ether | cut -d ' ' -f6
```

After this, I'm not sure how to make an array of the given data, since this will depend on each machine, and then ask the user which one to choose based on an integer as input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [select](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs)

```
select mac in `ip addr | grep ether | cut -d ' ' -f6`
do        
    if [[ -n $mac ]]
    then
        # put your command here
        echo $mac
        break
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I completely forgot about select.